# Applying aggregate function in terra to multiple raster files in a folder

Tags: land-cover, terra

I have 330 raster files in a folder showing landcover type. They are of a 10 m resolution and each file is approximately 3 MB in size.

I want to change the resolution of all of the files to 100 m and save it in a new folder.

I managed to change the resolution of a single raster using the following code:

library (terra)
#Load raster file
Landcover1 <- terra::rast("ESA_WorldCover_10m_2021_v200_N30E000_Map.tif")
#Aggregate by a factor of 10, with the new raster getting a mean (fun=mean, this can be max, min etc.)
a1 <- aggregate(Landcover1, fact=10, fun= "mean")
#Write raster to file
writeRaster(a1, "Landcover1newRes.tif")

**How can I perform this on all of the 330 rasters in the folder?**

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to be working

LandcoverGroupA <- list.files (path="path of the folder")
results <- lapply(LandcoverGroupA, function(x){
LandCoverGroupANew <- aggregate(Landcover1, fact=50, fun= "mean")
})